# Three.js CSS3DRenderer possible to control render order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I need to be able to force 1 or 2 elements to draw on top of the rest of the scene regardless of their actual distance from the camera.

Is there any way to control render order when using the CSS3DRenderer?

I have tried using zIndex and z-index on the dom elements the CSS3DObjects are created from with no effect.

object.renderDepth seems to have no effect.

I haven't pursued using overlapping scenes as this is quite complicated and I assume this won't work due to how CSS3DRenderer works and clears inside the dom...

I am using jquery as well if this provides for a simple solution or (unlikely) complicates things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `CSS3DRenderer`, you can force elements to render on top by adding them to a second scene, and rendering into a second canvas.

```
renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

renderer2 = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer2.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
renderer2.domElement.style.top = 0;
document.body.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );

scene.add( object );
scene2.add( object2 );
```

Then, in the animation loop:

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
renderer2.render( scene2, camera );
```

Comment: This solves the rendering issue but raises a new one: the renderer2 blocks interaction with the first renderer element i.e. clicks are absorbed by the renderer2 and never make it to anything underneath in renderer. I solved this with a little CSS by setting "pointer-events:none" on renderer2's dom object. Doesn't work in all browsers, but should work in anything that supports CSS3DRenderer. Entities that need to be clickable in the render2 need "pointer-events:visibleFill" or similar.